# Выравнивание блока по вертикали HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Опять эта проблема с выравниванием по высоте.

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
body{
 background: #fbfcfc;
}
#header{
 height: 350px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #525ea7;
}
#header_photo{
 height: 250px;
 width: 250px;
 background-image: url('http://aviasovet.ru/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE-%E2%84%96-1.jpg');
 background-size: 170%;
  background-position: 50% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 border-radius: 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Notes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <div id="header_photo">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
body {
  background: #fbfcfc;
}
#header {
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #525ea7;
  
}
#header:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
#header_photo {
  display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-image: url('http://aviasovet.ru/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE-%E2%84%96-1.jpg');
  background-size: 170%;
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Notes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="header_photo">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 2 flex:**

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
body{
 background: #fbfcfc;
}
#header{
 height: 350px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #525ea7;
  
      display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#header_photo{
 height: 250px;
 width: 250px;
 background-image: url('http://aviasovet.ru/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE-%E2%84%96-1.jpg');
 background-size: 170%;
  background-position: 50% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 border-radius: 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Notes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <div id="header_photo">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```